# How to install and launch the Gnome desktop from a Xenial 16.04 command line?

Tags: command-line, 16.04, gnome

I have installed Xenial 16.04 (command line only) and want to try the Gnome desktop. I believe Gnome 3.18 is the version that comes with the 16.04 release.

How can I install and then launch the Gnome desktop environment from my terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add gnome repositories.

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging`

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

And then install it:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt install gnome gnome-shell
```

Comment: Once I've done that, how would I launch it?

Comment: Perhaps with *startx*?

Comment: @CelticWarrior humm, `startx` just hangs for me?

Comment: did you reboot your computer?. If you did it and nothing happen then you need to install the gnome desktom manager "gdm" to have your user login window at atartup.

sudo apt-get install gdm
dpkg-reconfigure gdm

But I think that you only need to type startx to make it run

Comment: @xaviBansus Thanks I will try that. Can I get Gnome without using the ppa? I've heard people mention `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop`?

Comment: Yes, It works, it's another method. With the command you said i recommend you to install this too:   sudo apt-get install gnome-shell

Answer (score 2):

## Checking availability from default sources

Apart from installing from a ppa you could as well just use the meta-package `ubuntu-gnome-desktop` which is available in the default sources of 16.04 - at least according to `apt-cache policy`

```
apt-cache policy ubuntu-gnome-desktop
ubuntu-gnome-desktop:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 0.58.1
  Version table:
     0.58.1 500
        500 http://de2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     0.58 500
        500 http://de2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

## Checking gnome-shell version

Again using `apt-cache policy`:

```
apt-cache policy gnome-shell
gnome-shell:
  Installed: 3.18.5-0ubuntu0.1
  Candidate: 3.18.5-0ubuntu0.1
  Version table:
 *** 3.18.5-0ubuntu0.1 500
        500 http://de2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     3.18.4-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://de2.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 Packages
```

## Installing Gnome from default sources

So - to install simply run ....

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-gnome-desktop
```

## Choosing Gnome as session on login

Ignoring the fact if you use Lightdm or GDM or whatever else as Login manager - in all cases you should be able to choose the session-type (here Gnome) in the login-screen.